# what is the different between default, stronger and all operators in Pitclipse?

Tags: mutation-testing, pitest

I was using PITclipse on Eclipse to run PIT mutation tests on code. There are three type of operators in PITclipse: DEFAULT, STRONGER and ALL).

What is the different between them and the list of mutants listed in each operator?

Comment: Sorry about the folks who down-vote without explanation (wasn't me). People here like it, when you demonstrate that you put in effort to research or solve your issue, post what you've got and ask a specific question when you're stuck. This one looks too broad for this forum. What about trying [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=PITclipse+default+stronger)?

Comment: thank you for your advise, but I really search and I didn't find what I need. for example the operators that activated by default is conditional boundary. what about stronger operators?!!!

Comment: Actually I don't know either, but you could summarize your findings in your post and highlight the remaining open issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the existing groups here: https://pitest.org/quickstart/mutators/

Each group has a different set of mutators/operators. I know that DEFAULT only includes mutators very well tested. If you choose ALL you may include some mutators that come up with false positives. From my experience is not common, but it has happened once to me

Comment: thank you, can we generate mutants randomly using PIT tool?

Comment: I don't think PIT has some sort of API to simply generate mutants. Mutant generation is simply a step on the process of mutation testing

Comment: (ps: if the answer is what you were looking for, don't forget to upvote and accept it)